# Inscribed_radius is not updated by footprint?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, costmap, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a continuation of this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/233980/can-a-costmaps-inscribed_radius-and-circumscribed_radius-be-set-from-the-parameter-server/), I understand that inscribed_radius of a robot is calculated solely based on the [robot footprint](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/costmap_2d/src/layered_costmap.cpp#L176). Also, my understanding is that inscribed_radius is initialized [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/costmap_2d/src/layered_costmap.cpp#L66).

If my understanding is correct, then inscribed_radius will be minimum of itself and the footprint calculation.  [See here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/costmap_2d/html/footprint_8cpp_source.html#l00057)

Since the inscribed_radius has been initialized as 0.1, then if the footprint inscribed radius is larger than that, inscribed_radius will always remain 0.1. This is consistent with what I have seen in my testing as well.

Thanks,
Rico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360431/inscribed_radius-is-not-updated-by-footprint?/) by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I understand that inscribed_radius of a robot is calculated solely based on the robot footprint.

You are absolutly right the `inscribed_radius` is calculated in the function `calculateMinAndMaxDistances` that you linked. The part about the `inscribed_radius` initialized at `0.1` is correct too but it's just in order to have a default value in case you don't call `calculateMinAndMaxDistances`.

> then inscribed_radius will be minimum of itself and the footprint calculation

You've missed something in the function , the first instruction is :

```
min_dist = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
```

So the inscribed_radius isn't equal to `0.1` anymore (`std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` returns `DBL_MAX` which is the maximum possible value for a `double` : `1.79769e+308`, check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) for more details). It's set to this value in order to make sure that when you call :

```
min_dist = std::min(min_dist, std::min(vertex_dist, edge_dist));
```

`min_dist` can only be equal to `std::min(vertex_dist, edge_dist)` (or `DBL_MAX`), since `vertex_dist` and `edge_dist` are calculated from the footprint the `inscribed_radius` changes according to the footprint.

> This is consistent with what I have seen in my testing as well

You might not have changed the footprint (or just a little bit) when testing this, I tried with a circular footprint and I got these results :

```
robot_radius = 0.14 >> inscribed_radius = 0.13731
robot_radius = 1.14 >> inscribed_radius = 1.1181
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1